# How can I get the name property value From the array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

This is an array of data from the database. I want to show the name property from the array and This is also a laravel livewire project
how can I do this?
can I use it foreach loop?

***This is the Array**

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1431 ▼
 #items: array:5 [▼
   0 => App\Models\Reply {#1430 ▶}
   1 => App\Models\Reply {#1429 ▼
     #filleble: array:6 [▶]
     #connection: "mysql"
     #table: "replies"
     #primaryKey: "id"
     #keyType: "int"
     +incrementing: true
     #with: []
     #withCount: []
     #perPage: 15
     +exists: true
     +wasRecentlyCreated: false
     #attributes: array:9 [▶]
     #original: array:9 [▼
       "id" => 4
       "comments_id" => 1
       "name" => "Md. Munirujjaman"
       "email" => "mdmunirujjaman045@gmail.com"
       "reply" => "dkjfdkj"
       "notification" => 0
       "status" => 0
       "created_at" => "2021-01-12 03:01:47"
       "updated_at" => "2021-01-12 03:01:47"
     ]
     #changes: []
     #casts: []
     #classCastCache: []
     #dates: []
     #dateFormat: null
     #appends: []
     #dispatchesEvents: []
     #observables: []
     #relations: []
     #touches: []
     +timestamps: true
     #hidden: []
     #visible: []
     #fillable: []
     #guarded: array:1 [▶]
   }
 ]
}
```

**This is the Code of my project **

```
   public $reply;

    public function getModalId($item)
    {
        $this->reply     = Reply::where('comments_id', $item)->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
        dd($this->reply);

    }
```

I am trying to get this of my laravel project
and it give me the error message

ErrorException
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View:

```
 @foreach($reply as $cmtReply)
   {{$cmtReply->name}}
  @endforeach
```

This is database data
how can I use this
`{{$reply}}`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
return View:make('viewname')->with('reply', $this->reply);

@foreach ($reply as $CommentReply)
  Hello, {{$CommentReply->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I already use this, this is a livewire component

Comment: Not understand what mean live write component ? @mdmunirujjaman27

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase ok sure let me edit and update.

Answer (score 0):

You can access each property of any model by using the arrow -> followed by the name of the property. In your case, you want to access the "name" property, so you just type `$myComment->name`. See: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-models

If you are using Laravels blade engine, you can use the same syntax within the `{{ ... }}` in your view.

To loop through a list of entities, you have to pass the variable which contains this list in your controller, when accessing the view. See: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views

After that, you can access the variable with the name you gave to it in the passed array.

Comment: I'm getting a specific reply name  this way  ```   @foreach(array($reply) as $item)
                                      
                                             Name:{{$item[0]['name']}}
                                    @endforeach``` But now I need to count all reply to this comment how can I do this